# Is $\int_0^a\frac{f(x)^2}{\int_0^x f(t)\,dt}\,dx\geq\int_0^a \frac{g(x)^2}{\int_{0}^{x}{g(t)}\,dt}\,dx.$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose $f(x)\geq g(x)>0$ and that $f,g$ are suitably defined so that the integrals below make sense. I want to know if

$$\int_0^a\frac{f(x)^2}{\int_0^x f(t)\,dt}\,dx\geq\int_0^a \frac{g(x)^2}{\int_{0}^{x}{g(t)}\,dt}\,dx.$$

I guess I'll need some assumption to take care of fact that the integrals are improper, as the denominators are zero when $x=0$. If needed, I can also assume that $f$ and $g$ are decreasing functions.

I'm actually more interested in the discrete counterpart to this problem but was hoping that the continuous version might give some insights. Does this integral inequality resemble some other problem? What techniques are helpful for such problems.

Comment: I tried correcting the missing delimeter--modify if I messed something up by accident.

Comment: Both integrals are infinite. However, note that the integrand on the left is $\ge$ the integrand on the right.

Comment: I have tried to make the question more clear. Do you still that it is not well formulated?

Comment: For any particular $a$ you can make the inequality either hold or not hold by choosing appropriately large constants of integration for either $G$ or $F$. (In other words, I think the problem became severely underspecified when you changed the denominators from the integrals in the title to the arbitrary antiderivatives in the edit).

Comment: The integrand on the left may not be more than the integrand on the right. The denominator on the left is larger than that on the right.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to write
\begin{align}
\int_0^a\frac{f(x)^2}{\int_0^x f(t)\,dt}\,dx-\int_0^a \frac{g(x)^2}{\int_{0}^{x}{g(t)}\,dt}\,dx \ge0
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
0 &\le\int_0^a\left[{\frac{f(x)^2}{\int_0^x f(t)\,dt} -\frac{g(x)^2}{\int_{0}^{x}{g(t)}\,dt} }\right]dx 
\\
&=\int_0^a\left[{\frac{f(x)^2\int_{0}^{x}{g(t)}\,dt-g(x)^2\int_{0}^{x}{f(t)}\,dt}{\int_0^x f(t)\int_{0}^{x}{g(t)}\,dt}} \right]dx \tag{1}
\end{align}
Setting $A:=\int_{0}^{x}{f(t)}\,dt$ and $B=\int_{0}^{x}{g(t)}\,dt$
thus (1) becomes
\begin{align}
0 &\le
 \int_0^a\left[{\frac{Bf(x)^2 -Ag(x)^2}{AB }} \right]dx \tag{2}
\end{align}
which holds if and only if $ Bf(x)^2 -Ag(x)^2 >0$ and $AB>0$ **or**
$ Bf(x)^2 -Ag(x)^2 <0$ and $AB<0$.

Obliviously, we can conclude that the primary assumptions are the both quantities are positive (negative) and $f,g$ continuous.

Thus, from (2)
\begin{align}
0 &\le
 \int_0^a\left[{\frac{Bf(x)^2 -Ag(x)^2}{AB }} \right]dx
\\
&=\int_0^a\left[{\frac{\left(\sqrt{B}f(x) -\sqrt{A}g(x)\right)\left(\sqrt{B}f(x)+\sqrt{A}g(x)\right)}{AB }} \right]dx
\end{align}
Without loss of generality assume $A,B>0$ thus 
\begin{align}
\left(\sqrt{B}f(x) -\sqrt{A}g(x)\right)\left(\sqrt{B}f(x)+\sqrt{A}g(x)\right) >0
\end{align}
which means that $\sqrt{B}f(x) -\sqrt{A}g(x)>0$ or we write $\sqrt{B}f(x) >\sqrt{A}g(x)$ i.e., it is enough to assume  $f>g$ for all $x$.

The summary of assumptions is that $f,g$ non-zero, positive, continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$  (or integrable, so far is enough) and $f>g$. To guarantee the imroper integrals, $f,g$ must be bounded as $x\to \infty$.

Let me know if i missed something.

Comment: Thanks for the input! The only problem that I see is that $(2)$ might hold even $Bf(x)^2-Ag(x)^2<0$ for some values of $x$. That means, unless I'm mistaken, the "only if" is not true is general.